# Python Simple-Salesforce - Fetch Bulk API Job Id in result

Tags: bulk-api, python, simple-salesforce

Is there some way to get Bulk API Job Id in job results?

```python
object_type = self.sf_connection.bulk.__getattr__('Case')
results = objecttype._bulk_operation(use_serial = True, operation = 'delete', data = db_dict_list, batch_size = 10000)
```

The results here doesn't return job id. Is there a way to get job id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [salesforce-bulk](https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk) package instead.

Eg:

```
from time import sleep

from salesforce_bulk import SalesforceBulk


def startBulkAPI():
    bulk = SalesforceBulk(sessionId="00D0k0000009cvA!*****CAdVT8datyhmWPhDr5yIOSt.NxQWgu6I_XIuD", host="https://*****.my.salesforce.com")
    job = bulk.create_query_job("Task", contentType='CSV')
    batch = bulk.query(job, "select Id from Task WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:6")
    bulk.close_job(job)
    while not bulk.is_batch_done(batch):
        sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    startBulkAPI()
```

Here `job` gives back the job Id, and `batch` will give each batch id (chunking batch id)